# Query does not return all the rows I thought it would

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query

```
SELECT category_name, categories.category_id, problems.problem_id, COUNT(problems.problem_id) as num_problems
FROM categories 
JOIN problem_categories 
ON problem_categories.category_id = categories.category_id
JOIN problems 
ON problems.problem_id = problem_categories.category_id
WHERE is_top = 1
GROUP BY category_name, categories.category_id, problems.problem_id;
```

It returns 2 rows. But there are about 9 items that match the is_top = 1 clause. I am not sure why they are not returned as well?

Here is what currently gets returned:

```
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| category_name | problem_id | num_problems |
+---------------+------------+--------------+
| Entertainment |         46 |            1 |
| Home          |         49 |            2 |
+---------------+------------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here are my tables:

```
mysql> describe categories;
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| category_id          | int(10)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| creator_id           | int(10)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| category_name        | varchar(100)  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| category_description | varchar(5000) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| category_date        | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_top               | tinyint(1)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| problem_count        | int(8)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> describe problem_categories;
+---------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| problem_category_id | int(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| problem_id          | int(10) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| creator_id          | int(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| category_id         | int(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| category_date       | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe problems;
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| problem_id          | int(10)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| creator_member_id   | int(10)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| problem_title       | varchar(100)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| problem_description | varchar(3000) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| problem_date        | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| upvotes             | int(7)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| downvotes           | int(7)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date_updated        | date          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any ideas why the other top categories do not get returned with their counts?

Thanks!!

By the way, the counts for the 2 categories which are returned are correct.

Comment: Its hard to answer your question definitively the way that you are asking it without seeing all the data. Remember that inner joins produces only whats common between tables and gets more restrictive as you add tables. Consider taking the `group by` statement out and see if you get the 9 results you were looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The join condition `problems.problem_id = problem_categories.category_id` looks incorrect.

This should presumably be `problems.problem_id = problem_categories.problem_id`.

You might also want to consider `LEFT JOIN` to bring back counts of categories with no problems.

Comment: the other categories do have problems associated with them. That is part of my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Whithout seeing your data its pretty tough to tell but I'd recommend changing the Inner JOINS to LEFT joins

e.g.

```
SELECT category_name, categories.category_id, problems.problem_id, COUNT(problems.problem_id) as num_problems
FROM categories 
LEFT JOIN problem_categories 
ON problem_categories.category_id = categories.category_id
LEFT JOIN problems 
ON problems.problem_id = problem_categories.category_id
WHERE is_top = 1
GROUP BY category_name, categories.category_id, problems.problem_id;
```

Since you're have an issue with specific problem id I usually write a SQL statement to help debug  this by doing something like

```
SELECT is_top , category_name, categories.category_id, problems.problem_id
FROM 
       problems
       LEFT JOIN problem_categories 
        ON problems.problem_id = problem_categories.category_id
       LEFT JOIN categories 
      ON problem_categories.category_id = categories.category_id

WHERE  problems.problem_id = 1234 --Whatever the ID is that you think should be showing up
```

This will help identify if is_top is really true as well as identify and any assumptions I made about the JOINS (e.g. nulls in the joined fields)

Comment: yes making it left-join returned the correct number of records. But in the newly returned records the counts are zero. But in reality the counts are not zero.  See this page for example: http://www.problemio.com/category.php?category_id=1 - it shows that this category has 9 associated records for example. But in the query it has a zero next to it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are doing two inner joins with other 2 tables that may not have a corresponding row.